# Listening to component's state change from different component using React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have a `Page` component that is rendered within `App` using `</Outlet>`. Within the `Page` component I would like to use a state (a simple text provided via search `input`) which is set in `App`.

I was able to send and receive the state during `Page` mounting via `navigate("/page", { state: { searchQuery } });` executed from `App`, but unfortunately this approach failed when the state of `searchQuery` changed.

Is there a simple mechanism which will allow `Page` to listen to the changes of `App selectQuery` state in React Router v6 and if so what's the solution?

```
// index.tsx
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      <Route path="page" element={<Page />}></Route>
    </Route>
  )
);
```

```
// App.tsx 
function App() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>("");

  return (
    // ...
    <AppBar component="nav">
      // Input text field which sets setSearchQuery onChange
    </AppBar>
    // ...
      <Outlet />
    // ...
}
```

```
// Page.tsx
function Page() {
  //...
  return (
    // ...
    // usage of a App searchQuery 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using outlet context:

```
function App() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>("");

  return (
    // ...
    <AppBar component="nav">
      // Input text field which sets setSearchQuery onChange
    </AppBar>
    // ...
      <Outlet context={searchQuery}>
    // ...
  )
}
```

```
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

function Page() {
  const searchQuery = useOutletContext();

  return (
    // ...
    // usage of a App searchQuery 
    // ...
  )
}
```

For more information, see this documentation: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.8.0/hooks/use-outlet-context